# I want to implement drilldown for heatmap or heatstock of highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, heatmap, drilldown

I am not able to add drilldown for heatmap or heatstock of highcharts. There are examples present for drilldown where only one data is required.

**E.g:**
`enter code here`enter code here`data: [5, 7, 3]

But not for 2D or 3D data.

**E.g:**

```
1. data: [[1479220200000, 107.11],
        [1479306600000, 109.99],
        [1479393000000, 109.95]]

2. data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24]]
```

Can anyone please check if this can be implemented or its a bug in highcharts.?

Comment: Please share a stackblitz of the code. So we will know what kind of error, or where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `drilldown` functionality to `heatmap` in the same way as to other series types. Example:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        value: 10,
        drilldown: 'animals'
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        value: 10
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 1,
        value: 19
    }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 0,
        value: 92
    }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
        value: 58
    }],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000'
    }
}],
drilldown: {
    series: [{
        id: 'animals',
        data: [
            [0, 9, 7],
            [1, 10, 4],
            [2, 6, 3]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mzfpjeht/